# React router unique path for every element of array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, path, react-router

I've got an array of elements like:

const arr = [

```
 0: {name: aaaa, age:33, color: red}
 1: {name: bbbb, age:22, color: blue}
 2: {name: cccc, age:55, color: yellow}
```

]

And I would to do when i write a path like http://localhost/aaaa it would render this actual element of an array and I want to define it at react router.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with a single route that has a `name` param:

```
<Route path="/:name" component={MyComponent} />
...
componentDidMount() {
    const arr = [
        {name: aaaa, age:33, color: red},
        {name: bbbb, age:22, color: blue},
        {name: cccc, age:55, color: yellow}
    ];
    const match = arr.find( item => item.name === this.props.match.params.name );
    // Render match
}
```

Comment: Could you show me some examples? Because i don't know why in render match is undefined

Comment: Can you post your full component? If you aren't getting `match` as a prop then you aren't passing router props correctly. You can also use `withRouter` HOC from `react-router-dom` to get the router props passed into the component.

Answer (score 0):

On parent element looks like this

< PropsRoute exact path='/:name' component={PlanetInfo} onePlanet={singlePlanet}
planetList={planet />

and child component

class PlanetInfo extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){

```
    const match = this.props.onePlanet.find( item => item.name === this.props.match.params.name );
}
backToPlanetList = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/')
}
render(){
    console.log(match)//here is undefined
    const {onePlanet} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.backToPlanetList}>Back to the list</button>
            <h1>name: {onePlanet.name}</h1>
            <p>climate: {onePlanet.climate}</p>
            <p>diameter: {onePlanet.diameter}</p>
            <p>rotation period: {onePlanet.rotation_period}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}